# Phone arguments on Blackberry OS 4.5

Tags: blackberry

When I invoke code like this on blackberry using (compiling) JDE 4.5.

```
public void invokeCall() {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                PhoneArguments phoneArgs = new PhoneArguments(
                        PhoneArguments.ARG_CALL, "12345");
                Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_PHONE, phoneArgs);
            }
        });
    }
```

The result was that a pop up screen showed up and told that the **phone number used to access extensions within my corporation has not been set**.

In order to disable it I set the smart dialing country code to unknown.

(This problem did not occur when compiling on JDE 5.0)

**Is there any blackberry code to set this automatically?**

Comment: Can you please describe where did you set "smart dialing country code"? And about the compilation level, are you sure the device where you tested with 5.0 is the same one where you tested with 4.5?

Comment: i set smart dialling country code on options->call management/phone options->smart dialling->change country code (but in device and simulator blackberry OS 4.5 there is no options like that)... and the simulator and device where i tested with 5.0 are the same one i tested with 4.5..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thanks for pointing out that smart dialing matters when making calls to extensions and injecting DTMF tones, because I have a similar project where this may cause problems.

In 4.5, you can configure smart dialing aswell, but the menu is not shown in main options menu, only in the phone app options. From the "Desktop", press a numeric key to bring the phone app to foreground, then press menu -> Options -> Smart Dialing -> Country Code.

Now, to set it programmatically, use [this version](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/invoke/PhoneArguments.html#PhoneArguments%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) of PhoneArguments constructor. So in your code, replace your arguments with this line to disable smart dialing:

```
PhoneArguments phoneArgs = new PhoneArguments(PhoneArguments.ARG_CALL, "12345", false);
```

Comment: Oh my Lord, how could i didnt notice the third parameter... thanks for your answer, i really apreciate it.